# Xamarin.iOS application failed to run on simulator(Probably after last Xamarin.iOS update)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

iOS apps are not starting in iPhone simulator(iPhone 5 - iOS 10.0 used ). 
There are errors from logs
`CoreSimulator.log`:

```
mlaunch[1482] <Error>: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to open "com.xamarin.acquaint-native" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.xamarin.acquaint-native" failed., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe15ceb7540 {Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=Unspecified}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified.}
```

`System.log(Debug mode from Xamarin Studio or VS 2015)`:

```
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini CoreSimulatorBridge[5136]: Requesting launch of com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS with options: {
        arguments =     (
            "-monodevelop-port",
            51746
        );
        environment =     {
            "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" = "/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/monotouch-fixes.dylib";
        };
    }
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini CoreSimulatorBridge[5136]: [Common] [FBSSystemService][0xe350] Sending request to open "com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS"
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.3D2EDEEE-4261-4B99-9B31-971D08B0124E.launchd_sim[5110] (UIKitApplication:com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS[0xe451][5510]): Program specified by service does not contain one of the requested architectures: 
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini SpringBoard[5127]: [Common] Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS[0xe451]': No such process (err 3)
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini SpringBoard[5127]: [Common] Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x7a79b830; com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS; pid: -1>
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini CoreSimulatorBridge[5136]: [Common] [FBSSystemService][0xe350] Error handling open request for com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS: <NSError: 0x7b871a30; domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain; code: 1 (RequestDenied); reason: "The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified."> {
        description = "The request to open "com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS" failed.";
        failureReason = "The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified.";
        underlyingError = <NSError: 0x7b871c10; domain: FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain; code: 1 (Unspecified)> {
            description = "The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)";
        };
    }
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini CoreSimulatorBridge[5136]: Error Launching: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to open "com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified., NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS" failed., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b871c10 {Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=Unspecified}}}
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.3D2EDEEE-4261-4B99-9B31-971D08B0124E.launchd_sim[5110] (UIKitApplication:com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS[0xea1e][5511]): Program specified by service does not contain one of the requested architectures: 
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini SpringBoard[5127]: [Common] Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS[0xea1e]': No such process (err 3)
Nov 10 00:00:01 macmini SpringBoard[5127]: [Common] Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x80a24f00; com.companyname.FasterNotesMobile.iOS; pid: -1>
Nov 10 00:00:05 macmini calaccessd[5164]: 25534103: Beginning CalScheduledTaskCacheTrimAndExtendAndUpdateOverdue
Nov 10 00:00:05 macmini calaccessd[5164]: 25534103: ScheduledTaskCache last saved 499237200
Nov 10 00:00:05 macmini calaccessd[5164]: 25534103: today is EKCalendarDate <0x7c17e740> { date = Thursday, November 10, 2016 at 12:00:00 AM CST }, comparisonResult is -1
Nov 10 00:00:05 macmini calaccessd[5164]: 25534103: Updating overdue with today 500450400.000000
```

The log above are for acquaint pre build application. I tried several other application, the same story.
It used to work fine. 
I am using latest Xamarin iOS SDK update(that maybe the issue)

Comment: I tried to create single view application from project's template. The same problem. Everything works fine till i have updated Xamarin.iOS SDK/xCode.... It may not be related but that is the only modification i did to my development  environment

Answer (score 4):

Got same problem with a new project and the latest Xamarin.
To fix it I had to change "Supported architectures" to "i386" in the project options. The default was "x86_64".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of Xcode?
You won't be able to simulate on IOs 10 unless you have Xcode 8.2 (or 8.1, not sure) installed on your Mac station.

Comment: Do you have the simulators downloaded?